# ¿Como pasar elementos seleccionados de un checkedlistbox a un listbox con C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Hola a todos antes que nada gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leerme. Estoy haciendo programa usando visual studio 15 community programando desde C#. En el programa me conecto a una base de datos hecha en SQL Server 2008 de la cual obtengo claves de algunos productos que son para venta. Lo anterior lo hago desde una clase llamada "conexión" a la cual le paso todos los parámetros correspondiente y cargo los resultados de la query en un checkedlistbox con la finalidad de que el usuario pueda seleccionar los productos que desea. Los objetos seleccionados se pasan (o por lo menos eso es lo que debería hacer) a un listbox para que pueda visualizar solamente los seleccionados pero no lo hace, no se si alguien puede decirme que estoy haciendo mal u orientarme por favor. Gracias de antemano.

```
    class conexion{
      public void claves_semanas(CheckedListBox clb)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Productos;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=creedence;Password=fortunateson"))
            {
                string query = "select DS_productos FROM tiend.C_productos WHERE FE_INICIO > '2016-01-10' ORDER BY FE_INICIO";   //aqui omiti los datos por razones de que no puedo dar la información de los productos el caso es que necesito ver los productos que se dieron de alta desde el 2016-01-10
                SqlCommand buscador = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(buscador);
                da.Fill(dt);
                clb.DisplayMember = "DS_productos";
                clb.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

}

Hasta ahí termina el código que uso para la conexión, ahora este es el código que uso en el main

```
     foreach (var s in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(s.ToString());
        }
```

Obviamente marca error, aunque no se porque sinceramente. ACTUALIZACIÓN.

El error que da es este en el listbox: System.Data.DataRowView
Eso es lo unico que se alcanza a apreciar.

También intente usar el evento 'ItemCheck' de esta forma

```
       private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        string item = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
            listBox1.Items.Add(item);
        else
            listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
    }
```

A lo cual solo me devuelve en listbox la palabra 'colección' desconozco por que pase esto ya que mis conocimientos son bastante básicos y por mas que busque documentación en el MSDN no encontré nada que me pudiese servir.

Tengo que aclarar también que antes de usar todo el código que puse anteriormente usaba este código en mi clase:

```
      public void claves_semanas(CheckedListBox clb)
    {
        int stop = 1;
     dr8 = cmd8.ExecuteReader();
                while (stop > 0)
                {
                    while (dr8.Read())
                    {
                        clb.Items.Add(dr8["DS_SEMANA"].ToString());
                    }
                    clb.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    dr8.Close();
                    stop = -1;
                }
          }
```

y en el main usaba este

```
       foreach (string s in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
           listBox1.Items.Add(s);
        }
```

Y funcionaba bien salvo por un detalle, el cual es que los datos me salian repetidos 2 veces, creí haberlo solucionado en la clase con la variable stop, para hacer que el ciclo solamente se hiciera una vez, pero nunca resulto, lo cual me llevo a usar el código que coloque hasta arriba, con ese código si logré que los datos se mostrasen solamente una vez, aunque no puedo hacer que estos se muestren en el listbox.

Espero y puedan ayudarme. 
Saludos

Comment: `Obviamente marca error, aunque no se porque sinceramente.` por favor añade el error. Además ¿qué tipo de aplicación estás desarrollando, winforms, web?

Comment: Hola @Mauricio el error que da es este mira: System.Data.DataRowView, aunque aparece directamente en el listbox y no como un error normal no se a que se deba.

Comment: `System.Data.DataRowView` no es un error. Revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4875730/4092887).

Comment: Hola que tal  @Mauricio Muchas gracias, en la liga que colocaste encontré la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Declara en tu clase:

```
    private BindingList<string> DatosCheckBox = new BindingList<string>();
    private BindingList<string> DatosLista = new BindingList<string>();
```

Ahora en tu consulta

```
 public void claves_semanas(CheckedListBox clb)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Productos;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=creedence;Password=fortunateson"))
        {
            string query = "select DS_productos FROM tiend.C_productos WHERE FE_INICIO > '2016-01-10' ORDER BY FE_INICIO";   //aqui omiti los datos por razones de que no puedo dar la información de los productos el caso es que necesito ver los productos que se dieron de alta desde el 2016-01-10
            SqlCommand buscador = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            var rdr = buscador.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                DatosCheckBox.Add(rdr["DS_productos"].ToString());
            }
            checkedListBox1.DataSource = DatosCheckBox;
            listBox1.DataSource = DatosLista;
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

En el evento de tu CheckedListBox:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        var index = e.Index;
        var listbox = sender as CheckedListBox;
        var item = DatosCheckBox.Where(W => W == listbox.Items[index].ToString()).Single();

        switch (e.CurrentValue)
        {
            case CheckState.Unchecked:
                DatosLista.Add(item);
                break;
            case CheckState.Checked:
                DatosLista.Remove(item);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Nota: si tu objeto de la base de datos es de tipo compuesto vas a necesitar sustituir en las BindingList por el tipo que usas

Comment: Vale muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Jesus Rodríguez checaré lo que me dijiste y voy a estudiar que son las bidinglist.

Answer (score 0):

Hola he resuelto el problema a través del link que puso @Mauricio

Les dejo la forma en la que lo hice por si a alguien le llega a servir en un futuro.

Lo unico que tuve que hacer fue modificar el main de esta forma:

```
     private void agregarSemanasToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        string s = "";

        foreach (DataRowView drv in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            s += drv[0].ToString() + ",";
        }
        s = s.TrimEnd(',');
        listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }
```

Y con eso logré obtener el resultado deseado. Gracias a ambos por ayudarme.

Saludos